# Linux Docker container not reachable from the outside using Docker deskop for Windows?

Tags: docker

[Docker](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/) states that:

> Docker for Windows can’t route traffic to Linux containers

Does that mean that using a Windows host to run Linux containers that communicate together over a user-defined network (say 192.168.2.0/24), is not able to grant a different computer (that can access the Windows host) access to the containers? Even when publishing a suitable port?

Is there a workaround for this? Other than switching to a Linux host.